# How to open MFC application from only another MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have MFC app A. Now I want to create MFC app B. B must be opened from A, directly open is not allowed. How can I do that?

Please help, many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `B must be opened from A`? Do you mean A has to start B as a separate program after A is running?  Please take a look at [CreateProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: B must be separate application ? maybe it's enought for You to create B.dll loaded by A ?

Comment: In app A, we have a button, that will open app B as separate app. But we prevent user open app B by directly open exe file.

Comment: @Danie launch app B with a super secret switch on he command line from app A. In app B check if the super secret switch is on the command lien. If yes, then it as been launched by app and you can proceed, if no then just quit, that means that some user has lauched the .exe directly.

Comment: Then do as @CADDeveloper says. That is the best way as user will not be able to run a dll directly.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? Please read this: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running another app from your app is as simple as calling:

```
STARTUPINFO info={sizeof(info)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
```

And as  Michael Walz has suggested you can use special (secret) command line option to prevent the user from running the app directly.

Comment: Unless that user knows about Process Monitor… :-)

Comment: Simply calling `WaitForSingleObject` will block the message queue. But it may be all right, it depends on what the OP _actually_ want to do.

Comment: Passing both *lpApplicationName* and *lpCommandLine* to [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) is in the overwhelming majority of cases the wrong solution. Pick either one, depending on whether you need to pass command line arguments or not.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. Good catch. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Michael Walz. True, but I was assuming that Danie is familiar with WaitForSingleObject and Win API in general.